# Regular expression for legal case names

Tags: ruby, regex, text, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a regular expression for use in a Ruby program which matches legal case names in plain text.

I have come up with the following regular expression:

```
((([[:upper:]])+\s)?((([[:upper:]]+([[:lower:]])+)\s)+v\s((\b[[:upper:]]([[:lower:]])+)\s?)+(\(|\[)+\d+(\)|\])\s(\d+\s)?\w+\s(\w+)?(\s)?(\d+)?))
```

This almost does what I want but there are some edge cases where it fails to match.  I need an expression which will match the following cases (including the citation at the end):

1. Seele Austria GmbH & Co v Tokyo Marine Europe Insurance Ltd [2009] EWHC 2066
2. Darlington Building Society v O'Rourke James Scourfield & McCarthy [1999] PNLR 365

The expression that I have written works on the basis that legal case titles will be a series of Title Case Words with a v in the middle.  However, the ampersands in both of the above examples, together with the GmbH in example 1 are throwing things off and I only get a partial match (from Co v ... ) against 1.  I get no match at all for 2.

If anyone can show me how to change my expression so as to match both the above examples, I'd appreciate it.  The expression is also pretty unwieldy as it stands - maybe it can be simplified?

Comment: is `GmbH` correct?

Comment: it's like LLC, but in German. It stands for [Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesellschaft_mit_beschr%C3%A4nkter_Haftung)

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE_REGEXP = %r{
  (?<spaces>    \s+ ){0}
  (?<capword>   [[:upper:]] [[:alpha:]']+ ){0}
  (?<titleword> \g<capword> | & ){0}
  (?<title>     \g<capword> (?:\g<spaces> \g<titleword>)* ){0}
  (?<year>      \[ \d{4} \] | \( \d{4} \) ){0}
  (?<endbit>    [[:upper:]]+ \g<spaces> \d+ ){0}

  \g<title> \g<spaces> v \g<spaces> \g<title>
  \g<spaces> \g<year>
  \g<spaces> \g<endbit>
}x
```

Ruby's Oniguruma is very powerful, and gives you the ability to write very legible regular expressions even when you need something more complex.

EDIT: forgot about the year and whatever the other thing at the end is. Will fix in a bit.

EDIT2: added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with to match both cases.

```
(([A-Z]('[A-Z]|[a-z][A-Z])?[a-z]+[A-Z]?|&)\s)+(v\s)(([A-Z]('[A-Z]|[a-z][A-Z])?[a-z]+[A-Z]?|&)\s)+\[\d{4}\]\s[A-Z]+\s\d+
```

Here's the breakdown

```
(([A-Z]('[A-Z]|[a-z][A-Z])?[a-z]+[A-Z]?|&)\s)+
```

This will match `&`, and words like `Adam`, `O'Neal`, `McCarthy`, it takes into account the different case possibilities for names.

```
(v\s)
```

This will match the letter `v` followed by a space

```
(([A-Z]('[A-Z]|[a-z][A-Z])?[a-z]+[A-Z]?|&)\s)+
```

Same as before.

```
\[\d{4}\]\s
```

This will match `[`, then 4 numbers, then `]`

```
[A-Z]+\s\d+
```

This last part will the 4 capital letters, then the digits. I'm not sure if the letters and numbers are limited in some way, if the capital letters is always 4 letters, and the numbers are 3 to 4 digits, you can do this

```
[A-Z]{4}\s\d{3,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches with both example:

```
([A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+|\s&\s).*(\sv\s)[^\[]*\[[0-9]{4}\]\s[A-Z]+\s[0-9]+
```

But if it doesn't work for another one, just pass me the text that I will try to adapt my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would not attempt to match the string with a single regex. Consider the following.

**Code**

```
R1 = /
     \s+v\s+ # match 'v' preceded by >= 1 spaces and followed by >= 1 spaces
     |       # or
     \s+\[   # match a left bracket preceded by >=1 spaces
     |       # or
     \]\s+   # match a right bracket followed by >=1 spaces
     /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode 

def legal_case_name?(str)
  party1, party2, year, id = str.split R1
  valid_party?(party1) && valid_party?(party2) && valid_year?(year) && valid_id?(id)
end

def valid_party?(party)
  return false if party.nil?       
  party.split.all? { |word| word == '&' || word =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/ }
end

def valid_year?(year)
  return false unless year =~ /\A\d{4}\z/
  (1950..2040).cover? year.to_i
end

R2 = /
     EWHC\s+\d{4}  # match 'EWHC' followed by >= 1 spaces and then 4 digits
     |             # or
     PNLR\s+\d{3}  # match 'PNLR' followed by >= 1 spaces and then 3 digits
     |             # or
     ABC\s+\d{5}   # match 'ABC' followed by >= 1 spaces and then 5 digits
     /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode 

def valid_id?(id)
  (id =~ R2) ? true : false
end
```

Some of these methods would probably need to be modified to reflect requirements.

**Examples**

```
legal_case_name? "Seele GmbH & Co v Tokyo Insurance Ltd [2009] EWHC 2066"
  #=> true
legal_case_name? "Darlington Soc v Scourfield & McCarthy [1999] PNLR 365"
  #=> true
legal_case_name? "Darlington Soc vs Scourfield & McCarthy [1999] PNLR 365"
  #=> false
legal_case_name? "Darlington Soc v Scourfield & McCarthy [1921] PNLR 365"
  #=> false
legal_case_name? "Darlington Soc v Scourfield & McCarthy [1921] PNLR 3652"
  #=> false
```

**Explanation**

Suppose

```
str = "Seele GmbH & Co v Tokyo Insurance Ltd [2009] EWHC 2066"
```

Then

```
party1, party2, year, id = str.split R1
  #=> ["Seele GmbH & Co", "Tokyo Insurance Ltd", "2009", "EWHC 2066"]
party1
  #=> "Seele GmbH & Co" 
party2
  #=> "Tokyo Insurance Ltd" 
year
  #=> "2009" 
id
  #=> "EWHC 2066" 
valid_party?(party1)
  #=> true 
valid_party?(party2)
  #=> true 
valid_year?(year)
  #=> true 
valid_id?(id)
  #=> true
```